# Convert dtype='<U55201' into numpy array

Tags: python, json, numpy

I have a dataset that I didn't create myself. I disassembled the file in matlab to get the arrays that I am interested in and converted to json there. The array I wanna import into Python is called 'Y_test.mat'. This is part of my code:

```
mat = spio.loadmat('Y_test.mat', squeeze_me=False)
print mat
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
{'__version__': '1.0', '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI64, Created on: Sat Dec 16 10:25:44 2017', 'Y_test': array([ u'[1,2,3]'], dtype='<U55201'), '__globals__': []}
```

Now I wanna convert the Y_test into a numpy array but I just can't get it. I tried np.array(ast.literal_eval()) but this gives me the followig error:

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

I am in no way an expert in python so please excuse me if I missed something utterly obvious.

Thanks in advance.
Alex

Comment: The string is in unicode format did you try `str[mat] `and then convert it to numpy array?

Comment: I will try and let you know the result. I get this error when trying this approach: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Use the json module

Comment: What is this variable on the MATLAB side?

Answer (score 0):

The function `loadmat` returns a dictionary of variables contained in the `.mat` file. It is the case that your file contains a single variable whose name coincides with the name of the file itself. Next, to get a numerical array from a string you may evaluate it. In this case you will get a list which has to be transformed to a bumpy array. So try this:

```
actual_numpy_matrix = np.array(eval(mat['Y_test'][0]))
```

Comment: I used this and I actually got a step further. I now get [ u'[1, 2, 3]'] as the printout for print(str(numpy_matrix)). Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the output of numpy_matrix?